# Python pickle seems to break inside class, but not in command line script

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, pickle

I've been trying to unpickle some dictionaries from the database. I've reverted to using the marshal module, but was still wondering why pickle is having such a difficult time unserializing some data. Here is a command line python session showing essentially what I am trying to do:

```
>>> a = {'service': 'amazon', 'protocol': 'stream', 'key': 'lajdfoau09424jojf.flv'}
>>> import pickle; import base64
>>> pickled = base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(a))
>>> pickled
'KGRwMApTJ3Byb3RvY29sJwpwMQpTJ3N0cmVhbScKcDIKc1Mna2V5JwpwMwpTJ2xhamRmb2F1MDk0MjRqb2pmLmZsdicKcDQKc1Mnc2VydmljZScKcDUKUydhbWF6b24nCnA2CnMu'
>>> unpickled = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(pickled))
>>> unpickled
{'protocol': 'stream', 'service': 'amazon', 'key': 'lajdfoau09424jojf.flv'}
>>> unpickled['service']
'amazon'
```

This works all fine, but when I try this inside of a factory method for a class, it seems like the pickle.loads part errors out. The strings I am trying to load are pickled the same way as above. I've even tried copying the exact string that is pickled in the command line session above and just trying to unpickle that, but with no success. Here is the code for this latter attempt:

```
class Resource:

    _service = 'unknown'
    _protocol = 'unknown'
    _key = 'unknown'

    '''
    Factory method that creates an appropriate instance of one of Resource’s subclasses based on 
    the type of data provided (the data being a serialized dictionary with at least the keys 'service', 
    'protocol', and 'key'). 
    @param resource_data (string) -- the data used to create the new Resource instance. 
    '''
    @staticmethod
    def resource_factory(resource_data):
        # Unpack the raw resource data and then create the appropriate Resource instance and return. 
        resource_data = "KGRwMApTJ3Byb3RvY29sJwpwMQpTJ3N0cmVhbScKcDIKc1Mna2V5JwpwMwpTJ2xhamRmb2F1MDk0MjRqb2pmLmZsdicKcDQKc1Mnc2VydmljZScKcDUKUydhbWF6b24nCnA2CnMu" #hack to just see if we can unpickle this string
        logging.debug("Creating resource: " + resource_data)
        unencoded = base64.b64decode(resource_data)
        logging.debug("Unencoded is: " + unencoded)
        unpacked = pickle.loads(unencoded)
        logging.debug("Unpacked: " + unpacked)
        service = unpacked['service']
        protocol = unpacked['protocol']
        key = unpacked['key']

        if (service == 'amazon'):
            return AmazonResource(service=service, protocol=protocol, key=key)
        elif (service == 'fs'):
            return FSResource(service=service, protocol=protocol, key=key)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this after making some simplifications and then debugging in django. The main issue was that there were some errors in the Resource class itself that were preventing the correct completion of the resource_factory method. First, I was trying to concatenate a string and dictionary, which was throwing an error. I also had some errors elsewhere in the class where I was referring to the instance variables _service, _protocol, and *key withouth the '*' (typos).

In any case, the interesting thing was that when I used this code within Django's custom field infrastructure, the errors would get caught and I did not see any actual message indicating the problem. The debug statements suggested it was a problem with loads, but actually it was a problem with the debug statement itself and some code that came later. When I tried to implement this behavior using model properties instead of custom model fields for the data I was saving, the errors actually got printed out correctly and I was able to quickly debug.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. How are you testing it?

```
import logging
import base64
import pickle
class Resource:
    @staticmethod
    def resource_factory(resource_data):
        resource_data = "KGRwMApTJ3Byb3RvY29sJwpwMQpTJ3N0cmVhbScKcDIKc1Mna2V5JwpwMwpTJ2xhamRmb2F1MDk0MjRqb2pmLmZsdicKcDQKc1Mnc2VydmljZScKcDUKUydhbWF6b24nCnA2CnMu" #hack to just see if we can unpickle this string
        # logging.debug("Creating resource: " + resource_data)
        unencoded = base64.b64decode(resource_data)
        # logging.debug("Unencoded is: " + unencoded)
        unpacked = pickle.loads(unencoded)
        logging.debug("Unpacked: " + repr(unpacked))
        service = unpacked['service']
        protocol = unpacked['protocol']
        key = unpacked['key']

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
Resource.resource_factory('')
```

yields

```
# DEBUG:root:Unpacked: {'protocol': 'stream', 'service': 'amazon', 'key': 'lajdfoau09424jojf.flv'}
```

Comment: I'm running this under a django environment using apache mod_wsgi. Perhaps there is some problem with that then? It's really strange because the shell session above is done in the same django environment (python manage.py shell). The problem occurs when trying to do the lookups from the database (I'm using the Resource class to drive a special model field in Django that reads from a db column where the serialized data lives).